# Bulkified generation of unique 6-character alphanumeric IDs, with strict validation criteria

Tags: apex, bulkification, math

I have a requirement to generate a unique 6-character alphanumeric ID for records on a bulkified before-insert trigger, on an object already containing about 5 million records and expected to grow to upwards of 40 million over the next couple years. The ID must conform to the following rules:

1. Must contain at least one number and one letter
2. Every character in the ID must be unique
3. Cannot contain the numbers 0 or 1, or the letters O or I

My current approach is essentially to create an auto-incrementing base-32 field which skips the values that don’t conform to rules 1 and 2, and uses W, X, Y, and Z instead of the characters mentioned in rule 3.

I have this “working” already, but the method I’m using to skip the invalid values is clearly too inefficient for a before-insert trigger. Brute force sequential validation is not viable because sometimes there are long gaps between valid numbers. For instance, there are over a million consecutive invalid values between 32VUTS and 34WX25 (103807932 and 104858693 in base-10). My current solution spans this gap with only about 33k values checked, but it still consistently uses up 7-8 seconds of the 10-second CPU time governor limit.

Current implementation:

```
Integer lastFound = 103807931; // base-10 value of last ID used, retrieved from custom setting

Integer recordCount = 200; // # of records in Trigger.new;

List<String> valid = new List<String>();
while(valid.size() < recordCount){
    valid.add(doIncrement(lastFound));
}

System.debug(Limits.getCpuTime());

public String doIncrement(Integer startAfter){
    Integer current = startAfter + 1;
    String current32 = decToBase32_Alt(current);    

    while(matchFormat(current32) == false){   

        List<Integer> chars = current32.getChars();        
        Integer position = -1;       

        for(integer i = 0; i < chars.size() - 1 && position == -1; i++){

            for(Integer j = i + 1; j < chars.size(); j++){
                if(chars[i] == chars[j]){
                    position = chars.size() - j - 2;
                    break;
                }
            }        
        }
        if(position > 0){
            current = current + 32^position;
        }
        else{
            current++;
        }

        current32 = decToBase32_Alt(current);
    }

    lastFound = current;
    return current32;
}    

// validation: all unique characters, at least one number and one letter
public Boolean matchFormat(String input){    
    return new Set<Integer>(input.getChars()).size() == input.length() && input.isAlpha() == false && input.isNumeric() == false;    
}

// base-10 to base-32, alternate character set
public String decToBase32_Alt(Integer val){

    List<String> charSet = new List<String>{'W','X','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','Y','J','K','L','M','N','Z','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V'};

        String result = ''; 

    while(val != 0){
        Integer remainder = Math.mod(val,32);
        val = Math.floor(val/32).intValue();
        result = charSet[remainder] + result;
    }        
    return result;    
}
```

I am not a mathematician, but intuitively it seems very likely that there is some way to do this much more efficiently. Any ideas?

I am also open to suggestions for other ways of achieving this requirement. I have considered random generation coupled with collision retries, as suggested by [**this answer**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66537/generate-unique-key-using-trigger#answer-66547), but I’m concerned that there would be far too many collisions given the number of valid IDs (about 126 million, I believe) and tens of millions of records.

Credit to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066334/javascript-convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal#answer-32067333) for implementation of the base-32 conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of thinking about the system as a single number, consider the system as a set of 6 smaller numbers. This lets you get rid of most of the naivety of a brute force algorithm.

Here's the version I came up with:

```
public class q173224 {
    public static Integer nextId(Integer value) {
        value++;
        Integer a = (value >> 25) & 31, b = (value >> 20) & 31, c = (value >> 15) & 31,
            d = (value >> 10) & 31, e = (value >> 5) & 31, f = value & 31;
        for(; a < 8; (b = 8) == 8 && (a = a + 1) >= 0) {
            for(; b < 32; (c = 0) == 0 && (b = b + 1) >= 0) {
                if(a != b) {
                    for(; c < 32; (d = 0) == 0 && (c = c + 1) >= 0) {
                        if(a != c && b != c) {
                            for(; d < 32; (e = 0) == 0 && (d = d + 1) >= 0) {
                                if(a != d && b != d && c != d) {
                                    for(; e < 32; (f = 0) == 0 && (e = e + 1) >= 0) {
                                        if(a != e && b != e && c != e && d != e) {
                                            for(; f < 32; f++) {
                                                if(a != f && b != f && c != f && d != f && e != f) {
                                                    return (a << 25) + (b << 20) + (c << 15) + (d << 10) + (e << 5) + f;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    Static String[] keys = '23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
    public static String base32encode(Integer value) {
        return keys[(value >> 25) & 31] + keys[(value >> 20) & 31] + keys[(value >> 15) & 31] + 
            keys[(value >> 10) & 31]  +  keys[(value >> 5) & 31]  +  keys[value & 31];
    }
}
```

P.S. I apologize for the ugly hacks, but this code is optimized for performance, not legibility.

A few explanations:

```
(X = Y) == Z
```

This is a trick to simulate Java's "," operator, which would have greatly simplified the code. In Java, it would have been written as:

```
X = Y, W++;
```

Of course, << and >> are left-shift bits, and right-shift bits; it's a lot easier than having to write things like `a / 33554432` and so on. Likewise, we're using `& 31` to get `Math.mod(value, 32)`. This entire code is optimized to run like greased lightning and for code coverage purposes (just pass in 0 and 1<<31 to get 100% coverage of nextId).

Finally, the first parameter, the initialization of the loop, isn't done in the traditional way, because we need to start the loop at a predetermined value instead of starting at 0 (or some specific value).

Converting this to Java, I found that there are actually a total of 126,282,240 unique ID values that fit your criteria, allowing 8 possible values in the first position, 24 possible values in the second position, and 32 possible values for all other positions, with no duplicate characters in any position. The code never has to go more than 10 false loops to find a unique value, instead of needing to skip hundreds of thousands of values one at a time; it can generate an ID in less than 2ms per ID.

This requires no random guesses, and just a single solitary database query to determine where to start. Keep in mind that you must use a query to get a row lock on your custom setting (FOR UPDATE) to make sure that you don't generate the same ID twice for transactions that are in-flight simultaneously.

Comment: I have a similar requirement to generate 6-chars unique IDs in c#. Mind sharing the answer in c# as I'm getting lost in the syntax.

Comment: @rm I wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/0694dc01948b07afcb7fa1da0de4a656) for you. Oddly, I get a slightly different numerical count for total Id values, but I have a feeling it's probably a glitch in this code, not the new version. Still, the difference is less than a million (~1%), so it's probably okay unless you need an exact match in functionality.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox. My requirement is slightly different. There will be no single db store to allow distributed id generations. We use GUID internally and the business rule is to additionally give human-readable ids for queries over the phone. We can live with a few duplicates to narrow down the query results.

Comment: just ran the `gist`. It seems no matter where i start with `value`, i end up with `1117317` which translate to `"234567"` base32. Is that correct behaviour?

Comment: Searching around, i found couple of solutions using some randomness. I am thinking of providing some randomness in` value` for `NextId`. what's your thought? and oh! Interestingly, I also found out that with randomness, the swear words are possible. would resorting to `Hex` still give me big pool of ids?

Comment: @rm Yes, the goal of this was to have incremental IDs that have unique values according to rules in the original question (no 0/1/I/L, no two characters the same, and never generate the same ID twice until all values are exhausted). You can certainly just choose a random number, but this had an additional uniqueness constraint that was meant to be fast. If you need random, go ahead and make something random. Hex would give you only 16 million Ids instead of 130 million. However, you could remove vowels to get rid of all swear words, too (and all real words).

Comment: I get `& 31` is modulo `32`, what's criteria for the choice of the shift numbers `25`, `20`, etc.?

Comment: @rm There are 32 possible "digits", and every five bits gives me 2^5 (32) possible bit combinations. This allows me to fit 6 base-32 numbers into 30 bits, leaving two bits of the Integer unused (bits 31 and 30). This is actually similar in principle to how hex strings work, except we use 5 bits instead of 4 to represent the additional 16 values that we can't represent in base-16. For example, 2 3 4 5 6 7 in binary renders as 00 00000 00001 00010 00011 00100 00101. There's nothing terribly magical going on here, it's just incrementing base-32 numbers until we have unique combinations.